# HTML table doesn’t refresh after Jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to cancel all user changes in the html form ( id=”edit_cat_frm”) (edit cells in tables, delete rows in table( id ‘cat_list’) and  changes order with  drag’n’drop) with reset button (id=”reset_edit_cat”), so I decide to do this with AJAX.

Jquery ajax request is OK, but my main HTML table with id ‘cat_list’ doesn’t refresh after it.

I can watch only old data in the table that were before AJAX request with all user changes.

What is wrong?

My jQuery code  from edit_category.js.

```
$("#reset_edit_cat").click(function(){

    $('#name_cat').hide(); 
    $('#desc_cat').hide(); 
    $('#access2').hide(); 

    $('<div id="loading"><div></div></div>').appendTo('body');
    $.ajax({
            type     : "POST",
            cache    : false,
            url      : "ajax_request.php", 
            data     : { action: 'sel_all_cat'},
            dataType : "json",
            success: function(jsonObject) {

                if (jsonObject.dat0 != "" && jsonObject.dat1 != "" && jsonObject.dat2 != "")
                { 
                    var dat0 = '<table id="cat_list" class="table-bordered table-striped table-condensed"><thead><tr><th>Назва</th><th>Порядок показу</th>'+
                    '<th>Спорідненість</th><th>Порядок в табл.</th><th></th></tr></thead><tbody>'+jsonObject.dat0+'</tbody></table>';
                    var dat1 = '<table id="access5"><thead><tr><th>Перегляд категорії</th><th>Перегляд зображень</th><th>Додавання зображень</th><th>Голосування</th>'
                    +'<th>Відправлення листівок</th><th>Читання коментар.</th><th>Додавання коментар.</th></tr></thead><tbody>'+jsonObject.dat1+'</tbody></table>';
                    var dat2 = '<table id="desc5">'+jsonObject.dat2+'</table>';

                    $('#acs').html(dat1).hide();
                    $('#dsc').html(dat2).hide();
                    $('#cat_list').hide("drop", { }, 1000); 
                    $('#inner').html(dat0);
                    $('#loading').remove();
                    $('#cat_list').show("clip", { }, 1000); 
                }
            }

    });

});
```

Here is code from ajax_request.php

```
public function select_all_cat($par)
{
    $sql = "SELECT @i:=@i+1 as RowNumber, cat_id,  cat_name,  left(cat_description,256) as cat_desc, cat_parent_id,  cat_order,  auth_viewcat,  auth_viewimage, auth_upload, auth_vote,  auth_sendpostcard,  auth_readcomment,  auth_postcomment FROM myfotogallery_categories, (SELECT @i:=0) as RowNumberTable ORDER BY cat_order";


    $row = $this->process($sql,true);
    if (array_key_exists('1', $row)) 
    {
        $i=1;
        $subcat_info = $this->list_cat_for_subcat($row);
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "<tr class='draggable' data-row='".$value['cat_id']."'>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "<td class='col1'><span data-type='text' data-elemName='cat_name'>".$value['cat_name']."</span>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "<input class='person-id' name='person-$i-id' value='person-$i' type='hidden' />".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "<input class='row-depth' name='person-$i-depth' value='";
            $rezult['dat0'] .= ($value['cat_parent_id'] == 0) ? '1': '2';
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "' type='hidden' />".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "</td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "<td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "<select class='row-weight' name='person-$i-weight'>".PHP_EOL;

            $arr = $this->category_opt($row,$i,$subcat_info);
            $rezult['dat0'] .= $arr[0];
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "</select>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "</td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "<td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "<select class='row-parent' name='person-$i-parent'>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= $arr[1];
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "</select>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "</td>".PHP_EOL;

            $rezult['dat0'] .= "<td class='col3'>".($value['cat_order']/10)."</td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "<td class='col4'><a href='#' class='row-delete' title='Видалити цей рядок'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat0'] .= "</tr>".PHP_EOL;

            $rezult['dat1'].= "<tr data-row='".$value['cat_id']."'>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='viewcat'>";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= $value['auth_viewcat']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='viewimage'>";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= $value['auth_viewimage']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='upload'>";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= $value['auth_upload']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='vote'>";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= $value['auth_vote']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='sendpostcard'>";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= $value['auth_sendpostcard']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='readcomment'>";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= $value['auth_readcomment']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='postcomment'>";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= $value['auth_postcomment']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
            $rezult['dat1'] .= "</tr>".PHP_EOL;

            $rezult['dat2'] .= "<tr data-row='".$value['cat_id']."'><td>".$value['cat_desc']."</td></tr>".PHP_EOL;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    else { 
        $rezult['dat0'] .= "<tr>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat0'] .= "<td class='col1'><span data-type='text' data-elemName='cat_name'>".$row['cat_name']."</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat0'] .= "<td class='col3'>".($row['cat_order']/10)."</td>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat0'] .= "<td class='col4'><a href='#' class='row-delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat0'] .= "</tr>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat1'].= "<tr data-row='".$row['cat_id']."'>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='viewcat'>";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= $row['auth_viewcat']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='viewimage'>";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= $row['auth_viewimage']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='upload'>";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= $row['auth_upload']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='vote'>";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= $row['auth_vote']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='sendpostcard'>";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= $row['auth_sendpostcard']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='readcomment'>";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= $row['auth_readcomment']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='postcomment'>";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= $row['auth_postcomment']==1 ? "Так" : "Ні";
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "</span></td>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat1'] .= "</tr>".PHP_EOL;
        $rezult['dat2'] .= "<tr data-row='".$row['cat_id']."'><td>".$row['cat_desc']."</td></tr>".PHP_EOL;}
    if($par == "2") 
    { return $rezult;}
    else { echo json_encode($rezult); }
}
```

This is my html code from browser.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD/XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml11-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ua" lang="ua">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>Сайт - Фотогалерея - Мій фотоальбом - Редагувати, видалити, змінити порядок категорії/підкатегорії</title> 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min1.css" media="screen">
    <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.ie7.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.responsive.css" media="all">
    <!-- Add jQuery main library  --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Add jQuery UI library  -->    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scripts/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap_my.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dialog-error.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/logout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/profile-other.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/reindex_category.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="css/ajax_loading.css"/>
    <style>
    .button.ui-button {font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; margin-top: 4px;}
    </style><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="css/edit_category.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" href="css/assets/jquery.tabledrag.css"/>
<script src="scripts/edit_category.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.tabledrag.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jQuery.makeEditable.js"></script>

</head><body>
    <div id="art-main">
        <header class="art-header clearfix">
        <div class="art-shapes"></div>                    
        </header>
        <nav class="art-nav clearfix desktop-nav">
        <table class="main_menu">
        <tr>
        <td width='80%'>
        <ul class="art-hmenu"><li><a href="fotoalbum-new.php" >Головна</a></li><li><a href="#" >Фотогалерея</a><ul><li><a id="y2012" href="#" target="_self" title="Фото 2012 року">2012 рік</a><ul><li><a id="y2012-slavsko" href="#" target="_self" title="Поїздка в Славсько взимку. Лижі">Славсько-січень</a><ul><li><a id="y2012-1901" href="foto.php?date=2012-01-19" target="_self" title="">19.01.2012</a></li><li><a id="y2012-2101" href="foto.php?date=2012-01-21" target="_self" title="">21.01.2012</a></li><li><a id="y2012-2301" href="foto.php?date=2012-01-23" target="_self" title="">23.01.2012</a></li><li><a id="y2012-2401" href="foto.php?date=2012-01-24" target="_self" title="">24.01.2012</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a id="y2013" href="#" target="_self" title="Фото 2013 року">2013 рік</a></li><li><a href="upload%20image.php"  title="Завантажити нове зображення на сайт">Додати фото</a></li><li><a href="uploaded_recently.php"  title="Нещодавно завантажені Вами зображення">Нещодавно Ви завантажили</a></li><li><a id="lastdnld"  href="lastdnld.php" target="_self" title="">Останні 10 завантажених зображень</a></li><li><a id="lastcomm"  href="top10_comment.php" target="_self" title="">Останні 10 коментарів</a></li><li><a id="top10" href="#" target="_self" title="Топ 10">Топ 10</a><ul><li><a  href="top10.php?param=rating" target="_self" title="">за рейтингом</a></li><li><a  href="top10.php?param=votes" target="_self" title="">за голосами</a></li><li><a  href="top10.php?param=hits" target="_self" title="">за переглядами</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="#" >Меню адміністратора</a><ul><li><a href="approve_uploaded_images.php"  title="Перевірити завантажені користувачами зображення">Перевірка завантажених зображень</a></li><li><a href="check_comment.php"  title="Перевірити додані користувачами коментарі">Перевірка коментарів</a></li><li><a href="#"  title="">Категорія/підкатегорія</a><ul><li><a href="add_category.php"  title="Створити нову категорію/підкатегорію">Створити</a></li><li><a href="edit_category.php" class="active" title="Редагувати, видалити, змінити порядок категорії/підкатегорії">Редагувати</a></li><li><a id="reind" href="#" title="Переіндексувати порядок показу категорії/підкатегорії">Переіндексація</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a href="#" >Меню користувача</a><ul><li><a id="profile_option" href="#"  title="">Профіль</a><ul><li><a href="profile-new.php?id=1" target="_self" title="редагування власного профілю">редагувати мій власний</a></li><li><a id="profile_other"  title="переглянути профіль користувача">іншого користувача</a></li></ul></li></ul></li><li><a  href="#">Контакти</a></li><li><a  id="id_logout" href="#">Вихід з сайту</a></li></ul>        </td>
        <td class="main_menu menu_2">
        Привіт <b>vga</b>! Радий Вас бачити.        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </nav>
        <!-- внутр зміст початок-->
        <div class="art-sheet clearfix">
            <div class="art-layout-wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="art-content-layout">
                    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
                            <table width=100% border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
    <td width=25% height=400 align=left valign=top>
    </td>
    <td id="middle" align=center>
    <form id="edit_cat_frm" method="POST" action="">
    <p class="head1">Редагувати категорії / підкатегорії</p>
    <div class="scroll_img"><div class="inner">
    <table id="cat_list" class="table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Назва</th>
    <th>Порядок показу</th>
    <th>Спорідненість</th>
    <th>Порядок в табл.</th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class='draggable' data-row='59'>
<td class='col1'><span data-type='text' data-elemName='cat_name'>Нова категорія</span>
<input class='person-id' name='person-1-id' value='person-1' type='hidden' />
<input class='row-depth' name='person-1-depth' value='1' type='hidden' />
</td>
<td>
<select class='row-weight' name='person-1-weight'>
<option selected value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
<option value='6'>6</option>
<option value='7'>7</option>
<option value='8'>8</option>
<option value='9'>9</option>
<option value='10'>10</option>
<option value='11'>11</option>
<option value='12'>12</option>
<option value='13'>13</option>
<option value='14'>14</option>
<option value='15'>15</option>
<option value='16'>16</option>
<option value='17'>17</option>
<option value='18'>18</option>
<option value='19'>19</option>
<option value='20'>20</option>
<option value='21'>21</option>
<option value='22'>22</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select class='row-parent' name='person-1-parent'>
<option selected value='0'>Відсутній</option>
<option value='person-2'>Літаки</option>
<option value='person-3'>Гори</option>
<option value='person-4'>Міста України</option>
<option value='person-5'>Cars</option>
<option value='person-6'>Girls and boys123</option>
<option value='person-7'>Nature</option>
<option value='person-8'>Aircraft</option>
<option value='person-9'>Animals</option>
<option value='person-10'>Buildings</option>
<option value='person-11'>Universe</option>
<option value='person-12'>Рибалка</option>
<option value='person-13'>Турпохід</option>
<option value='person-14'>Рідні краєвиди</option>
<option value='person-15'>Подорожі</option>
<option value='person-16'>Світ каміння</option>
<option value='person-17'>Вояки</option>
<option value='person-18'>Вояки і собаки</option>
<option value='person-19'>Котики та котяри</option>
<option value='person-20'>Мишки</option>
<option value='person-21'>Комашки</option>
<option value='person-22'>Кукурудза</option>
</select>
</td>
<td class='col3'>1</td>
<td class='col4'><a href='#' class='row-delete' title='Видалити цей рядок'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr class='draggable' data-row='31'>
<td class='col1'><span data-type='text' data-elemName='cat_name'>Літаки</span>
<input class='person-id' name='person-2-id' value='person-2' type='hidden' />
<input class='row-depth' name='person-2-depth' value='1' type='hidden' />
</td>
<td>
<select class='row-weight' name='person-2-weight'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option selected value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
<option value='6'>6</option>
<option value='7'>7</option>
<option value='8'>8</option>
<option value='9'>9</option>
<option value='10'>10</option>
<option value='11'>11</option>
<option value='12'>12</option>
<option value='13'>13</option>
<option value='14'>14</option>
<option value='15'>15</option>
<option value='16'>16</option>
<option value='17'>17</option>
<option value='18'>18</option>
<option value='19'>19</option>
<option value='20'>20</option>
<option value='21'>21</option>
<option value='22'>22</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select class='row-parent' name='person-2-parent'>
<option selected value='0'>Відсутній</option><option value='person-1'>Нова категорія</option>

<option value='person-3'>Гори</option>
<option value='person-4'>Міста України</option>
<option value='person-5'>Cars</option>
<option value='person-6'>Girls and boys123</option>
<option value='person-7'>Nature</option>
<option value='person-8'>Aircraft</option>
<option value='person-9'>Animals</option>
<option value='person-10'>Buildings</option>
<option value='person-11'>Universe</option>
<option value='person-12'>Рибалка</option>
<option value='person-13'>Турпохід</option>
<option value='person-14'>Рідні краєвиди</option>
<option value='person-15'>Подорожі</option>
<option value='person-16'>Світ каміння</option>
<option value='person-17'>Вояки</option>
<option value='person-18'>Вояки і собаки</option>
<option value='person-19'>Котики та котяри</option>
<option value='person-20'>Мишки</option>
<option value='person-21'>Комашки</option>
<option value='person-22'>Кукурудза</option>
</select>
</td>
<td class='col3'>2</td>
<td class='col4'><a href='#' class='row-delete' title='Видалити цей рядок'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr class='draggable' data-row='23'>
<td class='col1'><span data-type='text' data-elemName='cat_name'>Гори</span>
<input class='person-id' name='person-3-id' value='person-3' type='hidden' />
<input class='row-depth' name='person-3-depth' value='1' type='hidden' />
</td>
<td>
<select class='row-weight' name='person-3-weight'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option selected value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
<option value='6'>6</option>
<option value='7'>7</option>
<option value='8'>8</option>
<option value='9'>9</option>
<option value='10'>10</option>
<option value='11'>11</option>
<option value='12'>12</option>
<option value='13'>13</option>
<option value='14'>14</option>
<option value='15'>15</option>
<option value='16'>16</option>
<option value='17'>17</option>
<option value='18'>18</option>
<option value='19'>19</option>
<option value='20'>20</option>
<option value='21'>21</option>
<option value='22'>22</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select class='row-parent' name='person-3-parent'>
<option selected value='0'>Відсутній</option><option value='person-1'>Нова категорія</option>
<option value='person-2'>Літаки</option>

<option value='person-4'>Міста України</option>
<option value='person-5'>Cars</option>
<option value='person-6'>Girls and boys123</option>
<option value='person-7'>Nature</option>
<option value='person-8'>Aircraft</option>
<option value='person-9'>Animals</option>
<option value='person-10'>Buildings</option>
<option value='person-11'>Universe</option>
<option value='person-12'>Рибалка</option>
<option value='person-13'>Турпохід</option>
<option value='person-14'>Рідні краєвиди</option>
<option value='person-15'>Подорожі</option>
<option value='person-16'>Світ каміння</option>
<option value='person-17'>Вояки</option>
<option value='person-18'>Вояки і собаки</option>
<option value='person-19'>Котики та котяри</option>
<option value='person-20'>Мишки</option>
<option value='person-21'>Комашки</option>
<option value='person-22'>Кукурудза</option>
</select>
</td>
<td class='col3'>3</td>
<td class='col4'><a href='#' class='row-delete' title='Видалити цей рядок'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
</tr>
<tr class='draggable' data-row='25'>
<td class='col1'><span data-type='text' data-elemName='cat_name'>Міста України</span>
<input class='person-id' name='person-4-id' value='person-4' type='hidden' />
<input class='row-depth' name='person-4-depth' value='1' type='hidden' />
</td>
<td>
<select class='row-weight' name='person-4-weight'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option selected value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
<option value='6'>6</option>
<option value='7'>7</option>
<option value='8'>8</option>
<option value='9'>9</option>
<option value='10'>10</option>
<option value='11'>11</option>
<option value='12'>12</option>
<option value='13'>13</option>
<option value='14'>14</option>
<option value='15'>15</option>
<option value='16'>16</option>
<option value='17'>17</option>
<option value='18'>18</option>
<option value='19'>19</option>
<option value='20'>20</option>
<option value='21'>21</option>
<option value='22'>22</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select class='row-parent' name='person-4-parent'>
<option selected value='0'>Відсутній</option><option value='person-1'>Нова категорія</option>
<option value='person-2'>Літаки</option>
<option value='person-3'>Гори</option>

<option value='person-5'>Cars</option>
<option value='person-6'>Girls and boys123</option>
<option value='person-7'>Nature</option>
<option value='person-8'>Aircraft</option>
<option value='person-9'>Animals</option>
<option value='person-10'>Buildings</option>
<option value='person-11'>Universe</option>
<option value='person-12'>Рибалка</option>
<option value='person-13'>Турпохід</option>
<option value='person-14'>Рідні краєвиди</option>
<option value='person-15'>Подорожі</option>
<option value='person-16'>Світ каміння</option>
<option value='person-17'>Вояки</option>
<option value='person-18'>Вояки і собаки</option>
<option value='person-19'>Котики та котяри</option>
<option value='person-20'>Мишки</option>
<option value='person-21'>Комашки</option>
<option value='person-22'>Кукурудза</option>
</select>
</td>
<td class='col3'>4</td>
<td class='col4'><a href='#' class='row-delete' title='Видалити цей рядок'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
</tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div></div>
    <br>
    <div id="acs">
    <table id="access">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Перегляд категорії</th>
    <th>Перегляд зображень</th>
    <th>Додавання зображень</th>
    <th>Голосування</th>
    <th>Відправлення листівок</th>
    <th>Читання коментар.</th>
    <th>Додавання коментар.</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr data-row='59'>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='viewcat'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='viewimage'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='upload'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='vote'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='sendpostcard'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='readcomment'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='postcomment'>Ні</span></td>
</tr>
<tr data-row='31'>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='viewcat'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='viewimage'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='upload'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='vote'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='sendpostcard'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='readcomment'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='postcomment'>Ні</span></td>
</tr>
<tr data-row='23'>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='viewcat'>Так</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='viewimage'>Так</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='upload'>Так</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='vote'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='sendpostcard'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='readcomment'>Ні</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='postcomment'>Ні</span></td>
</tr>
<tr data-row='25'>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='viewcat'>Так</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='viewimage'>Так</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='upload'>Так</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='vote'>Так</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='sendpostcard'>Так</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='readcomment'>Так</span></td>
<td><span data-type='boolean' data-elemName='postcomment'>Так</span></td>
</tr>

    </tbody>
    </table></div>
    <div id="dsc">
    <table id="desc">
    <tr data-row='59'><td>опис нової категорії</td></tr>
<tr data-row='31'><td>фото літаків</td></tr>
<tr data-row='23'><td>  фото гір</td></tr>
<tr data-row='25'><td></td></tr>

    </table></div>
    <table id="name_cat"></table>
    <table id="desc_cat">
    <thead><tr><th>Опис категорії</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <table id="access2">
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit_cat"/>
    <div id="dat_name"></div>
    <table id="butn" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td class="btn2">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="create" value="Записати"/>
    </td>
    <td class="btn2">
    <input id="reset_edit_cat" type="reset" class="button" name="Cancel" value="Відмінити"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <!--// 3 колонка-->
    <td width=25% height=400 valign=center></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- нижня таблиця -->
    <table align="center" class="tab_below">
    <tr>
    <td style="padding-top:30px;">
    <p align="center">
    <a class="button" title="На головну сторінку" href="fotoalbum-new.php"><img src="fotogallery/images/house.png"></a>
    </p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- внутр зміст кінець -->     
        <footer class="art-footer clearfix">
              <div class="art-footer-inner">
                    <p>Авторське право © 2013, Гладких Владислав. Всі права захищені.</p>
                    <p class="art-page-footer">
                        <span id="art-footnote-links">Веб-шаблон створений з допомогою Artisteer.</span>
                    </p>
              </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a div with class = inner, not id = inner. Change the id or the jquery selector to `$('.inner')`

Comment: Thank you. It's my mistake. I confuse class and id.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an element with the id **#inner**, as indicated in edit_category.js, via the following line:

```
$('#inner').html(dat0);
```

You instead have an element with a class of inner, therefore just need to amend line above to the following:

```
$('.inner').html(dat0);
```